# Parse file using Python RE, and insert line break between the characters found

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I have a file where I need to insert a line break whenever I found this characters: }{

There are more than a thousand occurrences of it, so I need to be able to loop through every line of the file (about 4k lines)

I'm terrible at regular expressions, what I tried is this:

```
order_item = re.compile("\}{", re.I)

# creates the file
f = open("orderProductsStructuredDataFinal001", "w", encoding='utf-8')
# opens up the file with the unstructured data, and use it as a iterator
with open('orderProductsStructuredData3') as inf:
    for line in inf:
    order = [ast.literal_eval(op) for op in re.findall(order_item, line)]
    # ta-da! Now do something with the order
    f.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in order))
# closes the file
f.close()
```

EDIT:

```
with open('orderProdcutsStructuredData3') as inf, open('orderProdcutsStructuredData3') as ("orderProdcutsStructuredDataFinal001", "w", encoding='utf-8'):
for line in inf:
    line = line.replace('}{', '}\n{')
    f.write(line)
```

Comment: Since you are dealing with literal strings, if you want to be efficient, do not use regex and use a simple string replacement of `}{` with `}\n{`

Comment: Tried this, get this error:
: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there...:

```
with open('orderProductsStructuredData3') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        line = line.replace('}{', '}\n{')
        f.write(line)
```

Note no RE is needed for this specific task, just a string replacement.

As a side note, just embed this into another `with` for the file you're writing -- no reason to switch to an open and a close for it...!  I.e:

```
with open("orderProductsStructuredDataFinal001", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    with open('orderProductsStructuredData3') as inf:
        for line in inf:
            line = line.replace('}{', '}\n{')
            f.write(line)
```

You could put both `open`s in a single `with`, to similar effect; but in this case they're so long that this would reduce legibility in my opinion.

Comment: You mean like this:
Edited original post

Comment: Not quite, your edit is using the wrong syntax.  Let me edit my A to show what I mean.